# Newbie - Javascript code on a mac to control Chrome

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome

I've been learning javascript looking through through openstack and need a little guidance, I've written the below code to open a website in chrome (my default browser), wait 5 seconds, and then refresh it 10 times using do/while loop.

Does it look OK as I want to run it from the terminal? I've been running this inside Chrome developer console and want to run it on my mac (10.9.5), is it a case of just running it through automator?

Many thanks for any help!

```js
var vcount = 0;

function sleep(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

do {
  window.location.assign("https://www.w3schools.com");
  sleep(10000).then(() => {});
  vcount++;
}
while (vcount < 10);
```

Comment: no, because `sleep(10000).then(() => {});` doesn't "pause" - also, once you change the current location, this script will no longer be in the current page, therefore, won't run anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use *await* to really pause the exectution:

```
(async function(){
  do {
   window.location.assign("https://www.w3schools.com");
   await  sleep(10000);
   vcount++;
  } while (vcount < 10);
})();
```

Comment: Ah, thankyou Jonas, I was trying to find that type of command, I was searching for 'sleep' and 'wait' then stumbled on the method I used, I will use your code!

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot of ways to do what you want, @JonasW gave one of them, here is an alternative:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  const waitUntil = new Date().getTime() + ms;
  while (new Date().getTime() < waitUntil) true;
}
```

This will run without `await` / `Promise`.

**Edit**

⚠️ Also, you'll need to pack up everything in a function, so it won't freeze the browser because JavaScript is running on a single thread:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    /* Your code */
}, 0)
```

Comment: Thankyou Arthur, is there any reason to use one method above another? Also, how comes there are multiple methods of doing a single action?!

Comment: @PCF Yes, there is one reason: not all browsers support the same functions, `await` and `Promise` were introduced in a recent version of JavaScript, and are supported on the latest version of Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. If you use my method, it will be supported on more browsers, such as IE. And, yes, in every programming languages, there is a bunch of ways to do the same thing. It's like synonyms.

Comment: This is a worse way of doing it as it freezes the browser.

Comment: @JonasW. True, but if you do it in an asynchronous way, such as using `setTimeout(yourFunction, 0)`, it won't. Let me edit my answer .